# Cannot connect to Postgres from remote address

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I cannot connect from my machine to a server running Postgres. I think I've configured it all correctly. No firewall are present on the server.

I'm running Postgres 9.1.9 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

This is from /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I have `listen_addresses = '*'` in /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf

I've stopped and started the service multiple times.

`netstat -tulnp`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19312/mongod    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28017           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19312/mongod    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      978/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30239/postgres  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      978/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      30239/postgres
```

My iptable is empty.

When I try to connect to the server with

```
psql -U postgres -h <MY_IP>
```

I get:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
Is the server running on host "<MY_IP>" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any help? Thanks

tcpdump on port 5432:

```
16:33:10.548507 7c:c3:a1:a2:d9:27 (oui Unknown) > 00:00:5e:00:01:01 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 78: <MY_MAC> > <MY_SERVER>.postgresql: Flags [S], seq 95915852, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 1189142453 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

I can connect to postgres on the server (`psql -U postgres -h localhost`) but I cannot telnet on 5432 from my machine.

Comment: The configuration looks right to me, but connection timeout strongly suggests that there is a firewall dropping the packet.

Comment: Check your server logs - specifically, look for iptables, ufw, or SELinux messages.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the maching running the client might also have iptables rules set that block the out- or inbound part of the connections.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's firewall blocking your network traffic. There's no information in your message about networks (client and postgres server), but it looks like there are some firewall rules that blocks traffic between client and server.

Answer (score 0):

are you using ipv4 or ipv6.

because your tcpdump sample show ipv6 connection, and you dont have enabled ipv6 connection on the pg_hba.conf

::1/128  --------> loopback